# How to receive Authorization header in httpclient class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, token

Sending an `Authorization` header seems fairly straight forward:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "value");
```

Say I send this token to `https://example/api/endpoint`, how would I receive and check it in the API?

In my API I tried:

```
[Route("endpoint")]
[AcceptVerb("POST", "GET")]
private async Task <IHttpActionResult> Endpoint()
{
    var authHeader = Request.Headers.Authorization(); //returns null
    //...
    return Ok(data);
}
```

But this returns null. How do I receive the token in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
Request.Headers["Authorization"]
```

A variation of this could be:

```
Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any(k => k == "Authorization"))
```